# preset default date and time on an xpage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to set a default date and time on a inputfield on a xpage.
So far I can only set the date :

```
<xp:inputText id="enddate" value="#{viewScope.einddatum}">

    <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:test ="2023-05-03";

    return test ;

}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

With this string, the date is correctly selected and the time defaults to 00:00:00

When I try to add time to my test string , the selected date stops working ...

How can I pre select both date and time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a Java Date object with the desired date and time. This example will set the date and time to the current date and time:

```
<xp:inputText id="enddate" value="#{viewScope.einddatum}">
    <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        return new java.util.Date();    
    }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Similarly, this will set it to one week from now at 8.00 (using one way of many for instantiating a Java date object):

```
<xp:inputText id="enddate" value="#{viewScope.einddatum}">
    <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var dateTimeVariable = java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(7).atTime(8, 0);
        return java.util.Date.from(dateTimeVariable.atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());  
    }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: var testDate ="2023-05-03";
var testTime ='09:10';
var localDate1 = java.time.LocalDate.parse(testDate);
var time = java.time.LocalTime.parse(testTime);

return java.util.Date.from(localDate1.atTime(time).atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction !